# Iframe onclick link on modal

Tags: html, iframe

I have a problem with iframe href. I need after click on iframe video relink on modal.

I need after click on that iframe video relink to #modal-03

```html
<div class="column folio-item" data-aos="fade-up">
  <a href="#modal-03" class="folio-item__thumb" data-lity>
    <div style="padding-top: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
      <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" allow="autoplay;fullscreen" src="https://onelineplayer.com/player.html?autoplay=true&autopause=false&muted=true&loop=true&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdesignbydaniel.eu%2Fimages%2Fportfolio%2FMarble%2520animation%2520439x439.mp4&poster=&time=false&progressBar=false&overlay=false&muteButton=false&fullscreenButton=false&style=light&quality=auto&playButton=false"
        style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <span class="folio-item__text">Marble animation for @Artiffine</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- end folio-item -->
```

Comment: Why do you wrap all code in an A? That is not how As work

Comment: Is this for [Lity](https://github.com/jsor/lity) ?

Comment: @mplungjan Because I have the text on link too

Comment: @mplungjan No, it isn't

Comment: @mplungjan Even that repaired by you didn't help. I need link that video on #modal-03 too